# combining from two lists into one class Python

Tags: python, list, class

Basically, I want something along the lines of:

```
for coin in all_coins["result"] and coin2 in all_coins2["result"]:
    specifiedlist.append(Crypto(coin, coin2))
```

Any help pointing me into the direction of a proper function or formatting would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `for coin, coin2 in zip(all_coins['result'], all_coins2['result'])` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` to create your permutations in a list comprehension

```
from itertools import product
specifiedlist = [Crypto(coin, coin2) in product(all_coins["result"], all_coins2["result"])]
```